# Create Account with Process Builder and Writeback to Opportunity

Tags: process-builder

I am trying to set up a process on the Opportunity object.  If certain fields are entered, the Process should create a new Account.  I then want the new Account linked to a lookup field on the Opportunity.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this in the Process Builder?

Comment: Your opportunity is under an account (I think) and you want to create a new Account based on certain opportunity fields and after creation, that account will be linked up as a look up to this Opportunity?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but in a different lookup field than the standard Account lookup on the Opp.

Comment: what are the criterias of creating this account?

Comment: It needs to be created if the Account related to the Opp is of a certain type.  Then the Account that needs to be created must have a Name, Country, State/Province.

Comment: you can handle this through trigger

Comment: With process builder you will really need to have it calling a headless flow to complete this as I think it will not be possible to do the record create and then the link to the Opportunity with Process Builder.

Comment: Creation of account can be done through process builder then believe this new account will not have any reference with base opportunity; so based on some key field information opportunity record needs to be queried and updated (this second part has to be done using trigger in account object.

Comment: @Dave -- Do you have any resources on creating the headless flow?  I understand Process Builder, but I have found Flows to be very confusing.

Comment: I'll get an answer up tonight (UK time) showing how to do this declaratively with Process Builder and Flow if no one else has put it up before that.

Comment: @Dave -- Thanks for the direction.  I was able to create a Process and Headless Flow and it works like a charm.  Thanks!!